# onesignal notification limit to specific country

Tags: javascript, ionic3, onesignal

On my app push notification is going even the user is not at specific country.
I want to prevent notification to be sent across country.Notification should not fire outside of specific country.
I am using onesignal push notificaiton.
Please help.

[This is code when i send notification.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxlJP.png)

Comment: How can anyone help without knowing what is your code doing!!

Comment: I updated my questions with code.